# can a person marry more than one person

Tags: marriage

In Hinduism allowed to marry more than one person on both genders male and female.

In some of the lifes they accept or dont accept he/she will be get two marriages in their life.

Is it allowed in hinduism or any scriptures says about the same.

Comment: A man can marry multiple wives according to smriti but not vice versa.